# Make beamer <+-> overlays start hidden

Tags: beamer

I usually have slides with constructs like the following:

```
\begin{frame}{A frame title}
What am I trying to do here?
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
   \item Show some stuff
   \item Show more stuff incrementally
   \item ...?
   \item Profit!
\end{enumerate}

\only<+>{I'm just going to show this briefly}
\uncover<+->{...and then I'll replace it with this!}
\end{frame}
```

I'd like that to render *five* slides - the first showing only the question, and the first list item showing up first on the *second* slide.

I can do this by adding `\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{1}` at the top of the slide, but then I have to do this on every slide... I tried to hook into the frame template to do it, but it didn't have any effect. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How about adding a `\pause`?

Comment: @percusse That also has to be done on every slide plus it has to be located correctly.

Comment: You could use `[<+(1)->]` instead of `[<+->]`. You still have to do it on every slide, though.

Comment: @cfr Well you need to type `\begin{frame}` for each frame too. ;) Put it before the enumerate.

Comment: Use @cfr's approach, but define a custom environment: `\newenvironment{enumerateh}{\begin{enumerate}[<+(1)->]}{\end{enumerate}}`

Comment: @percusse True. I was just going by the apparent desire in the question to not have to issue a command every frame.

Comment: `[<+(1)->]` is great for many cases! I've been looking for how to do that, but I wasn't able to find it in the docs. However, there are cases when it isn't enough, for example if I happen to not have a list, but just using `\uncover`, `\only` et al.

Comment: @TomasLycken Expand your question to cover those cases you mention in your last comment.

Comment: @Jubobs: Done. Thinking about it, I think that a global offset of 1 to my entire document would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the only problem you have left is to execute `\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{1}` on every frame. This can be done by hooking it into the `frameenv`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@frameenv{%
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\endgroup%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\beamer@framecommand\expandafter\beamer@frameoptions\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody}}%
  \global\beamer@envbody{}\def\beamer@begin@stack{b}%
  \begingroup
  \let\frame\beamer@collect@@body
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\frame}%
  \beamer@process@envbody%
  \addtocounter{beamerpauses}{1} %NEW
}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame title}
What am I trying to do here?
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
   \item Show some stuff
   \item Show more stuff incrementally
   \item ...?
   \item Profit!
\end{enumerate}

\only<+>{I'm just going to show this briefly}
\uncover<+->{...and then I'll replace it with this!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame title}
What am I trying to do here?
\begin{enumerate}[<+(1)->]
   \item Show some stuff
   \item Show more stuff incrementally
   \item ...?
   \item Profit!
\end{enumerate}

\only<1>{I'm just going to show this briefly}
\uncover<2->{...and then I'll replace it with this!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Normally I'd avoid hard-coding slide numbers, but it seems by far the easiest approach here. (An alternative, if you know the number of slides, would be to use a relative offset.)